Angular i18n: icons within text
What is the correct way to deal with texts that contain icons (or other arbitrary HTML that must not be translated) in Angular i18n? E.g.:
Allow alert <mat-icon>toggle_on</mat-icon> to modify the settings.

Is there away to let Angular just mark it with some placeholder, that is not translated?

Angular and its internationalisation package don't do the actual job of translating your app. They will just produce a language file that you would hand to a translator. You could instruct your translator to ignore icons. You could also mark content that you want ignored with a special class and then tell your translator to ignore content marked with that class.
If you don't want the content to appear in the language file, then do not annotate it with the i18n attribute.
Alternatively, if you want the browser to ignore certain elements when doing its own in-browser page translation, then you can mark elements with class="notranslate" and the browser will skip translating it. For example:
<p>This text will be translated. <span class="notranslate">And this text will not.</span></p>

